# Jquery click - thinks its the parent element, not the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children

When I click on a child element inside a div (the 'butMedWhite ' class) - the jquery thinks that I am clicking on the parent element ('.alternative') -  even when I dump 'this' inside the console it says i have clicked on the class 'alternative' (see code below) - not the 'butMedWhite ' class -  does anyone have any ideas why?
Here is the html:

```
<div class="alternative _activeCategory">
    <div class="alternative_inner"></div>
    <div class="expandable" style="display: block;">
        <div class=" criteriaContainer">
            <a class="butMedWhite altCreator">add rule</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
$('.altExpander').on('click', '.alternative', function(e) {
                    console.log(this);
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('_activeCategory')){
                        expandCategory($(this));
                    }else{
                        closeCategory();
                    }
                });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the click is defined for the container class alternative

Comment: Yeah that's because I want something to happen when the user clicks 'alternative' and also when they click on the child element - sorry I should have put that in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery provides as context to your callback the element on which you bound the event handler, just like the native DOM functions.

If you want the clicked element instead, don't use `this` but [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) :

```
$('.altExpander').on('click', '.alternative', function(e) {
     var clicked = $(e.target);
     console.log(clicked);
     if(!clicked.hasClass('_activeCategory')){
            expandCategory(clicked);
     }else{
            closeCategory();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your selector is ".alternative" in this line:

```
$('.altExpander').on('click', '.alternative', function(e)
```

If you want `this` to be the anchor tag, you need to use

```
$('.altExpander').on('click', '.alternative a', function(e)
```